# Pass custom json object in swagger with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to pass a custom json object as swagger request body. In Java we use `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)` annotation to hide some fields in swagger. But in my case I want to pass custom json object as swagger request body.

here's my code,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/verifyMobile", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Verify User otp", notes = "Verifies user email")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Boolean>> verifyMobile(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> verificationObj) {
        Boolean isUpdated = userService.mobileVerification(verificationObj.get("phoneNumber").toString(),
                verificationObj.get("mobileVerificationOtp").toString());
        Map<String, Boolean> objMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        objMap.put("success", isUpdated);
        return isUpdated ? ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(objMap) :
                ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).body(objMap);
    }
```

and I will be accepting bellow as request body,

```
{
    "phoneNumber":"+919038897580",
    "mobileVerificationOtp":"9399"
}
```

How can I implement this on swagger. Swagger body looks something like this.
[image]
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a `json` object as request body in `Swagger` you can create a model object.

Your model object can be as follows.

```
public class VerificationRequest {
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String mobileVerificationOtp;

    public VerificationRequest(String phoneNumber, String mobileVerificationOtp) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.mobileVerificationOtp = mobileVerificationOtp;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getMobileVerificationOtp() {
        return mobileVerificationOtp;
    }

    public void setMobileVerificationOtp(String mobileVerificationOtp) {
        this.mobileVerificationOtp = mobileVerificationOtp;
    }
}
```

Then you can edit this model where your endpoint is located as follows.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/verifyMobile", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Verify User otp", notes = "Verifies user email")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Boolean>> verifyMobile(@RequestBody VerificationRequest verificationObj) {
    Boolean isUpdated = userService.mobileVerification(verificationObj.getPhoneNumber(),
            verificationObj.getMobileVerificationOtp());
    Map<String, Boolean> objMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    objMap.put("success", isUpdated);
    return isUpdated ? ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(objMap) :
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).body(objMap);
}
```